# Magento 2: language pack not working properly after .csv file was edited

Tags: magento2, addtocart, csv, language, edit

I installed this language pack https://github.com/splendidinternet/Magento2_German_LocalePack_de_DE. Everything worked fine.

Then I edited the following line in the `magento-path\app\i18n\splendid\de_DE\de_DE.csv` file:

*"Add to Cart,Zum Warenkorb hinzufügen -> Add to Cart,In den Warenkorb"*

When I go to category page, at first everything looks fine:

[image]

but when I click on the 'add to cart'(In den Warenkorb) button , the button text changes back to the translation "Zum Warenkorb hinzufügen", which was there before I edited the `de_DE.csv` file:
[image]
[image]
[image]

When I reload the site everything looks good again:
[image]

I think it has something to do with JS. Any hints on solving this issue ?

**UPDATE:** Changed Code in `pub\static\frontend\<vendor>\<theme>\de_DE\Magento_Catalog\j‌​s\catalog-a‌​dd-to-cart.js`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
                var addToCartButtonTextDefault = 'In den Warenkorb'; //changed
                console.log("test1");         addToCartButton.removeClass(self.options.addToCartButtonDisabledClass);
                addToCartButton.find('span').text(addToCartButtonTextDefault);
                console.log("test2");
                addToCartButton.attr('title', addToCartButtonTextDefault);
            }, 1000);
```

Now it works

Comment: You should override this js file in your custom theme. If you change the code in `pub/static`,  the code will lose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`. As we can see, Magento uses Ajax for adding product to cart. In each state, there are some different texts:

```
$t('Adding...')
$t('Added')
$t('Add to Cart')
```

So, we need to translate for these texts.